Failed "ionic cordova run android" with "Could not find or parse valid build output file"
When I attempt to run the command ionic cordova run android --prod --release the build succeeds, however it fails with the following message: "Could not parse valid build output file"
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
 62 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 61 up-to-date
 Built the following bundle(s): 
 /Users/PATH_HERE/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab
 /Users/PATH_HERE/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/fitDEGREE.aab


 [ERROR] Could not find or parse valid build output file.
    
    Tried the following paths:
    -
    /Users/PATH_HERE/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/output.json
    -
    /Users/PATH_HERE/app/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/output-metadata.json"

There is no apk folder under platforms/android/app/build/outputs/ which makes sense that it's crashing, however I don't know how to make that appear?
I've been trying to get this to work for 2 days now. I've tried changing versions of everything I could think of. I've tried removing the android platform & adding it back. Tried changing my version of NodeJS from 18.13 to 16.13 not really sure what else to try at this point. I tried downgrading my version of ionic/cli from 7.2 to 6.2.
Any advice is greatly appreciated!
Here is my current ionic info output if it helps. Note i've been changing versions of everything trying to get it to work so this is just what it currently is.
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.9
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.4.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.1.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.1.2
   @angular/cli                  : 13.3.10
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 12.0.0 (cordova-lib@12.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 12.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, cordova-plugin-ionic 5.5.3, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 2.0.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   ios-deploy        : 1.12.2
   NodeJS            : v18.13.0
   npm               : 8.19.3
   OS                : macOS Unknown
   Xcode             : Xcode 16.0 Build version 16A242d


Turns out I was working on two branches using different versions of Java & Node.
Changing my versions to the following fixed it for me:
JAVA jdk1.8.0_202.jdk
NODE: v16.13.0
Cordova-android: 11.0.0
